# Failing to connect; my fault?

Tags: connection

A client has supplied the following info (fake values used here) for connecting to his host and doing my stuff. I have tried connecting from several locations and failed - the connection times out. Am I doing something wrong, or is he forgetting some crucial info?

IP: 216.x.y.z
MySql Password : password1
User : user1
Password : password2
SSH Port : 49226

==========

root password : password1
Hostname ; host.com
Username ; user2
Password : password3
FTP Port : 201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the port is actually forwarded correctly, no, you should be ok.

ssh is normally port 22, ftp is normally 21. Maybe they put in a typo ? - Otherwise maybe they havent set the port forwarding correctly on their network equipment.

Comment: Thanks. I have never used ssh, and don't know how to, so I left that out. What do I use to connect to a host with ssh? (on a Windows box)?

Comment: @Majid: PuTTY http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: you can use PuTTY, a very nice SSH client.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: They might have restricted access to the server- allowing only certain ip's access- did you provide them with your ip address? Otherwise, it sounds like it's their fault.